# how to display running commentary of cmd in textarea designed on gui application using swing in java

Tags: java, swing

After running one executable file from my gui application using swing in java,
i want to display running commentary of cmd in my textarea which i have taken on my gui applcation in lower half portion .How can i do it .
This is my code i have written for my Run button for running .exe file:-

```
private void runActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        System.out.println( "Running" );
        try
        {
            String [] command    = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "start",
                                     "runMatness.bat",
                                     "inputfile=" + myFilePath,
                                     "dbreporting=false" };
            Process myProcess    = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
            {
                displayresult.append(line);
            }//while
            input.close();
        }// eof try
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }//eof catch
```

where displayresult is my textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure after every

```
displayresult.append(line);
```

to call:

```
java.awt.Container#validate()
```

method of the enclosing container. Container is the component which receives your displayresult:

```
someContainer.add(displayresult);
```